# Selenium Python: youtube can't access to videos category

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

can't acess with selenium to the videos category of youtube, the homepage and the videos category got the same class and no id.

i tried to use the id of "tabsContainer" and then find the videos button to click on it but it didn't work if someone can help i'll apreciate !

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.